# Why is that woman considerd the woman that Rimuru is destined to be with?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

In episode 6, we learn that

> Shizu

is the woman Rimuru is destined to be with.  She shows up in the next episode.

> She also dies a couple of episodes later, the next day in-universe.  Aside from her showing up in the OP and ED, and being a quest-giver (for Rimuru to be a teacher) several episodes later, she doesn't have much going on in the series.

Why is she considered so important and "Rimuru's destiny"?  Why is she seemingly more important than Veldora, the ogre women, Miliam, etc?

> Why is she more important than any of the other monsters/spirits that Rimuru absorbed?

I'm only familiar with the anime, so if the manga/LN goes that much more in detail about this, then don't spoil it and leave the answer somewhat vague.

Comment: I interpreted "destined with her" to mean that their _meeting_ was fated, rather than her being very central to his life. Of course, she did have a large impact on his life too, as the answers mention. Plus, considering how soon she appeared, maybe the prediction was in the short term, and not supposed to be taken as his entire life's destiny.

Answer (score 3):

@earthling gave a good answer into the importance of her role in Rimaru's destiny. Below I want to give the ways in which she was always with him.

- Shizu was with Rimaru physically, forever, in his stomach.
- Shizu also lived on with him when Rimaru took her physical form.
- In a sense, she was also with him through the emotional connection of fulfilling her wishes. It's often said that a person lives on through their legacy and the memory of others. Rimaru fulfilled her wish and legacy of saving the Children. Shizu also lived on with him both in his memory and in Rimaru's journey to finish her quest of confronting Demon Lord Leon Cromwell.

So in many ways, she was always with him and thus was the person he was destined to and ended up being with.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from episode 6-8:

1. Shizu is the key by which Rimuru comes to know Demon Lord who summons Shizu (probably the main villain) and Rimuru is more or less the hero of this story.
2. Without Shizu, Rimuru might never know that someone (Demon Lord) can summon people from that world to this world.
3. Death of Shizu is essential for Rimuru's character development.
4. There is one promise Rimuru gave to Shizu, and fulfilling that promise will provide a certain path or goal to the story.

This is explained more in the manga.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.

Comment: Anyone who did watch anime should be able to understand my ans , so for reference watch anime episode 6 to 8.

Comment: 'Anyone who did watch anime should be able to understand my answer' Yes, but this is a Q&A site. Unlike other forums, this site relies on verifiable information. Speculations are allowed but a basis, specifically references, should be given on how and why you were able to arrive on that particular conclusion. There are no exceptions. <Continued below>

Comment: For example, '3) Death of Shizu is essential for Rimuru's character Development.' How did you arrive at this conclusion? Why is a character's death essential for someone to develop? People can still develop without someone close to them dying. Same is true for all other answers. Personally, this and the rest of your points needs more evidence and proof.

Comment: As W. Are has commented, a correct & sourced answer is far better than just a correct answer without any references (because others can't crosscheck it easily). Also, feel free to use `>!` (spoiler block) markdown syntax to hide some text if you want, as long as you can expand and improve your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I’m thinking about this. Because, when the imagine of the person destined to his surged, it showed her with the kids, but more specifically it showed Chloe hugging Shizu and the other kids looking. I think Shizu will always a very important part of Rimuru. She was the ignition for him to meet the kids and understand more about the world they are leaving in. I think she and the kids are part of his destiny.

However, I ask myself, is it really Shizu his destiny girl or was it Chloe? Being part of someone's destiny and being their destined partner are two different things. I think all of them are part of his destiny, but Chloe may be his destined woman. Because, when Rimuru and the kids are in labyrinth of the spirits, Chorona kisses Rimuru. We know she is Chloe's spirit from the future. This is my theory.